# Can i write a WatchKit app using Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

Can I use Swift for WatchKit? Or do I have to use objective C?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you are free to use either Objective-C or Swift when writing a WatchKit extension. On [the WatchKit developer page](https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/), there is a link to some sample code ("Lister") that has an accompanying Apple Watch app and is available in both Objective-C and Swift.

Comment: Yes sure you can go with Swift.